# Алгоритм для расчета путей

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть n пунктов. Между ними n - 1 путей.
Несколько последовательных путей объединяются в магистрали. Необходимо выбрать главный пункт, чтобы к нему можно было добраться  с любого пункта через как можно меньшее количество магистралей. Я создал цикл в котором n - 1 строк с путями превращаются в массивы и складываются в другой массив(вложенные массивы). Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен за внимание оказанную помощь!
Входные данные:

> n 
> n - 1 строк в которых указаны пути

Например `n = 5`

```
1. 2 3
2. 1 2
3. 4 1
4. 1 5
```

P.S.Вот код:

```
arr = []
n = int(input())
k = n - 1
for i in range(0, k):
    a = input()
    b = [a]
    arr.append(b)
```

P.P.S.Можно только алгоритм, без кода.

Comment: это случаем не задача коммивояжера?

Comment: Да она самая. В общем случае перебор

Comment: @Zhihar нет, маршрут не кольцевой, я забыл кое-что дописать в условии

Comment: так вроде коммивояжер не обязательно по кольцу ездит - смысл в том, что нужен полный перебор

Comment: `к нему можно было добраться` - откуда? Приведите настоящее условие

Comment: Из чего вдруг следует, что это задача коммивояжера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связный (надо полагать) граф из n узлов и n-1 рёбер есть дерево.

Первым делом проверяем степени всех узлов (количество смежных узлов, оно же количество рёбер из данного узла). Если степени только 1 и 2 - дерево линейное, и подойдёт любая вершина.

Иначе удаляем все узлы со степенью 2, соединяя смежные им. Таким образом, остаётся дерево с "магистралями".

Теперь ищем центр дерева. Для этого поэтапно: находим все вершины со степенью 1 (листья);
удаляем их. Снова находим, снова удаляем. Повторяем пока не останется одна или две вершины - это и есть центр. [Вот некая реализация](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/17974?locale=ru) данного этапа.